# Unity - How to make sprite be influenced by ambient light and fog?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Sorry for the noob question, I am still new to unity.

I am currently creating a game in unity that I have a mountain.
This mountain is a gameObject composed of a mesh filter with a plane and a mesh renderer with a Sprite/diffuse material of my mountain sprite.

When I change the ambient light on the RenderSettings I can see the mountain changing on the screen, but when I try to add some fog it doesn't change anything.
How can I make my mountain be influenced by both ambient light and fog?
Should I use a different shader on my material or something like that?

Here is my mountain gameObject:

[image: Mountain gameObject]

Here is my mountain material:

[image]

Comment: I've never done what you're trying to do, but I'm 95% sure that you need to use a shader that supports fog

Comment: That's the problem I still haven't found a sprite shader that supports fog.
All the fog shaders I found don't work with sprites and all the shaders that work with sprites don't support fog at all.

Comment: well unfortunately I can't help past this advice, but I usually get the source code for the shaders I need and combine them myself; it's usually not too complicated

Comment: How do you get the shaders' source code?

Comment: here is sprite/diffuse for example https://github.com/TwoTailsGames/Unity-Built-in-Shaders/blob/master/DefaultResourcesExtra/Sprites-Diffuse.shader

Comment: I'll take a look at that, thanks a lot, Ron!